# Some problems with the arrays dimensions i guess

Tags: python, arrays, 2d, newtons-method, index-error

With this code i want to find a minimum in from a two dimensional function using the newton method:

```
from numpy import array

from numpy.linalg import solve, norm

def newton2d(f, df, x, tol=1e-12, maxit=50):

    x = atleast_2d(x)

    for i in range(maxit):

        s = solve(df(x), f(x))
        x -=s
        if norm(s)<tol: print(x); print(i); break

f = lambda x: array([x[0]**2-x[1]**4, x[0]-x[1]**3])

df = lambda x: array([[2*x[0], -4*x[1]**3], [1, -3*x[1]**2]])


x = array([0.7, 0.7])

newton2d(f,df,x)
```

i think this code should work, but i get an error which goes as follows:

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

thanks for any help!!

Comment: Please format your code correctly

Comment: Why do you apply `atleast_2d` and what do you think it is doing? This is your problem.

Comment: No image of code please, just format it here correctly.

Comment: i think it makes sure that the definition of my function newton2d interprets the x it is given as an array rather than an integer...?

Comment: sure, got it, really just deleting x = atleast2d(x) solved the problem. thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is confusion between what is a 2D **array** and a 2D **vector**. A vector of *any* dimension, e.g. `x`, can be represented as a **1D** array. 2D arrays are for *matrices*, such as `df`.